# Using INDEX(MATCH()) to return the n'th value of a cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2007

I have a simple worksheet with 2 columns

[image]

I want to get all the results(on column "H") (I can get only the first occurrence,I want to know if I can get the others) that contains the value from cell G1, is that possible without a macro ? any way of doing it would be appreciated...Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ROW()` and `SMALL()` to get those instead of `MATCH()` since this always gets the first match.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($C$4:$C$7,SMALL(IF($D$4:$D$7=$G$1,ROW($D$4:$D$7)-(ROW()-1)),ROWS($D$4:D4))),"Null")
```

So, if the array `$D$4:$D$7=$G$1` returns true (i.e. the value equals that in G1), you will get the row numbers of these values, in this case, you will get 4 and 6. All the other will return `False`.

After some processing with `-(ROW()-1)`, the 4 and 6 become 1 and 3. those two values are what will be fed to the `INDEX`.

`SMALL()` then picks the smallest, starting with the 1st (you get `1` from `ROWS($D$4:D4)`) and when you drag the formula down, the `ROWS` become `ROWS($D$4:D5)` which gives 2, and `SMALL` ends up taking the 2nd smallest value, which is 3.

EDIT: Forgot to mention. You have to array enter the above formula. To do this, type the combination keys of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> after typing the formula (edit the formula again if necessary) instead of <kbd>Enter</kbd> alone.

Comment: thanks in advance, i'm trying to understand the logic of the formula, I've put the formula on F4 and dragged down and I got ~text 1~ and just null values as the rest ... am i missing somethin'?

Comment: @Stephenloky Oh, I forgot to mention. You have to array invoke this formula. After typing it, don't press enter, but press Ctrl+Shift+Enter to 'array enter it'. After that, you will see `{}` around the formula.

Comment: WOW! Magic!!! Thanks for the support, I really appreciate It. One more question , why do you set the array to D4-D7 not D4-D8
(as with C)?

Comment: @Stephenloky Also, you can use the 'Evaluate formula' under the tab 'Formulas' to see what happens in a step by step way.

Comment: @Stephenloky Aside from the `$D$4:$D$7=$G$1`, you can actually use any other reference. What ultimately matters is that you end up with the right number of rows. You could have used `ROW($E$4:$E$7)` just as well for instance.

Comment: Does I always have to set `total_row - 1` at the end of the formula , like you did ?

Comment: @Stephenloky I added that so that the formula still works if you add a row above/remove one above. The simplest would have been to use `ROW($D$4:$D$7)-3` there, but it breaks the formula easily when you insert/delete a row.