# excel lookup value on another sheet and return value of another column from that sheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formulas, vba

I have a workbook it has a main sheet called Players that has Ticket#, Table#, Name (then other information).

**Example:**

[image: Players]

I also have sheets with table assignments.

**Example:**

[image: Tables]

What I would like is for the sheet called table 1 to look through the Sheet Called Players for Table 1 and then return the Name of the person next to it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using INDEX(MATCH()) to return the n'th value of a cell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23701265/using-indexmatch-to-return-the-nth-value-of-a-cell) Alternatively you can also have a look at the following (more detailed) explanation: https://exceljet.net/formula/get-nth-match-with-index-match

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in 'Table 1'!B2,

```
=iferror(index(players!c:c, aggregate(15, 6, row(players!b$1:index(players!b:b, match(1e99, players!b:b)))/(players!b$1:index(players!b:b, match(1e99, players!b:b))=1), row(1:1))), text(,))
```

Fill down until you receive blanks.

Comment: That worked perfectly.  Another question is there a way to get the seat # to match the ticket # from the Players sheet as well?

Comment: Yes there is a way. Modify the above to retrieve the other column by matching the player name and table number (I assume that players could be at more than a single table). If you run into trouble, post a new question and *show your original effort** (working or not) to get the best response to your question. Posting requirements without showing original effort toward a solution if strongly frowned upon.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't suggest such approach but since you already set it then:

1. Add one helper column in each Table to find ROW number in Players sheet (it's possible without it but not recomanded. You can hide it if you like).
2. Enter this formula in cell A2 of new cell:

   =IFERROR(SMALL(IF(Players!$B$1:$B$100=1*TRIM(RIGHT(REPLACE(CELL("filename",A1),1,FIND("]",CELL("filename",A1)),""),2)),ROW($B$1:$B$100)),ROWS(A$2:A2)),"")

(Confirmed with ctrl+shift+enter, not just enter)

3. Now set INDEX value based on that row from players sheets:

   =IF($A2="","",INDEX(Players!C:C,$A2))

Extend formula to other cells and change columns as you like.

Comment: What would you suggest other than this?